# The return of string value is null or empty when I call the function using GetX in flutter

Tags: flutter, controller, flutter-getx

I want to call the string function, I use `package_info_plus` to get the packageName when I run the app, just like this:

```
class SplashScreenController extends GetxController {
  late String one = '';
  late RxString two = ''.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    _initPackageInfo();
    _setImage();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => Get.offNamed(Routes.DASHBOARD));
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {}

  Future<void> _initPackageInfo() async {
    final info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    one = info.packageName;
  }

  String _setImage() {
    if (one == 'com.package.one') {
      return two.value = Images.one;
    } else if (one == 'com.package.two) {
      return two.value = Images.two;
    } else {
      return two.value = Images.one;
    }
  }
}
```

And when I try to call `RxString two` inside Image.asset()

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(controller.two);
    return Obx(() => Scaffold(
            body: Container(
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          child: controller.one.isNotEmpty
              ? Image.asset(controller.two.toString())
              : const SizedBox.shrink(),
        )));
  }
```

It show the null value, is there any way for me to use the packageName value in conditional case and then calling it in `Image.asset()` widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewrite your controller and UI Code. Please check it out.

Controller (SplashScreen)

```
class SplashScreenController extends GetxController {
  late RxString one = ''.obs;
  late RxString two = ''.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    await _initPackageInfo();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => Get.offNamed(Routes.DASHBOARD));
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {}

  Future<void> _initPackageSetImage() async {
    final info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    one.value = info.packageName;
    switch(one.value){
      case 'com.package.one':
        two.value = Images.one;
        break;
      case 'com.package.two':
        two.value = Images.two;
        break;
      default:
        two.value = Images.one;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

UI (SplashScreen)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
            body: Container(
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          child: Obx((){
             print(controller.two.value);
             if(controller.one.value.isNotEmpty){
               return Image.asset(controller.two.value);
             }
             return const SizedBox.shrink();
           }),
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not related really to `Getx`, it's related to the Dart language programming and futures, here in this piece of code:

```
  @override
      void onInit() {
        _initPackageInfo();
        _setImage();
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => Get.offNamed(Routes.DASHBOARD));
        super.onInit();
      }
```

`_initPackageInfo()` is an asynchronous method, which needs time to resolve (so the `info` variable gets an `PackageInfo` instance ), this means that executing it synchronously will still get you the instance, but it will not wait for it, and it will run `_setImage()` immediately which at this point `PackageInfo.fromPlatform()` did not get resolved **yet**, so it's `null`, what you need to do is to make it wait until in have the instance **then** continues running other code :

```
 @override
  void onInit() {
    _initPackageInfo().then((val) {
     // this will be executed when _initPackageInfo() finishes.
     _setImage();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => Get.offNamed(Routes.DASHBOARD));
   });
  super.onInit();
  }
```

Comment: hello, i got another error from _initPackageInfo().then(() it showing error alert: The argument type 'Null Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(void)'.

Comment: sorry I forget setting a value in the `then` callback parameter, try again I fixed it